# The type or namespace name 'TwinCollection' could not be found

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Following the article to build an Azure Iot Edge module on Windows 10 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module

In the step 12 to Build IoT Edge Module, VS Code generates following error message: This is consistent experience in two different new Win 10 Environment I have tried to Build a docker image.

All the prerequisite steps have been successfully completed.

PS C:\Users\\Code\FilterModule> dotnet publish "c:\Users\\Code\FilterModule\FilterModule.csproj"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Restoring packages for c:\Users\\Code\FilterModule\FilterModule.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Users\\Code\FilterModule\obj\FilterModule.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Restore completed in 392.82 ms for c:\Users\\Code\FilterModule\FilterModule.csproj.
Program.cs(110,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TwinCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [c:\Users\\Code\FilterModule\FilterModule.csproj]

Anyone came across this issue and any advise on resolution?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial walks you through the process of pasting a bunch of code into your own sample project, but it leaves out a few necessary `using` directives. So if you try to compile as is, you get errors.

To work around this, you can add three `using` directives to the top of your Program.cs file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;     // for KeyValuePair<>
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared; // for TwinCollection
using Newtonsoft.Json;                // for JsonConvert
```

I've also submitted a PR to get the tutorial updated:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/4600/files